# How To Access Column In Subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, union

I'm having issues with the following query. For the subquery returning a sum of total results, I'm getting the error **Unknown column 'search.term' in 'where clause'**, I'm not sure how I'd be able to do this query properly? Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT *,
  (SELECT SUM(totalResults)
   FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as totalResults
         FROM media
         LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = media.userId
         WHERE media.title LIKE CONCAT('%', search.term, '%')
       OR media.description LIKE CONCAT('%', search.term, '%')
       OR media.tags LIKE CONCAT('%', search.term, '%')
       OR users.username LIKE search.term
         UNION ALL
         SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM reposts
         LEFT JOIN media ON media.id = reposts.mediaId
         LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = reposts.userId
         WHERE media.title LIKE CONCAT('%', search.term, '%')
       OR media.description LIKE CONCAT('%', search.term, '%')
       OR media.tags LIKE CONCAT('%', search.term, '%')
       OR users.username LIKE search.term
         )
  t) AS totalResults,
  MAX(search.timestamp) AS searchTimestamp
  FROM search
  WHERE userId = '1'
  GROUP BY search.term
  ORDER BY searchTimestamp DESC
```

Comment: How large are the counts?

Comment: The sum of them is 9 (8, 1), this is actually the implementation of the last query of mine you replied to.

Comment: Is there a column called term in the search table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is the doubly nested `SELECT` subqueries. Try this:

```
 SELECT  term,
         ( SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM media
           LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = media.userId
           WHERE media.title LIKE CONCAT('%', search.term, '%') 
              OR media.description LIKE CONCAT('%', search.term, '%') 
              OR media.tags LIKE CONCAT('%', search.term, '%') 
              OR users.username LIKE search.term
         )
         +
         ( SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM reposts
           LEFT JOIN media ON media.id = reposts.mediaId
           LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = reposts.userId
           WHERE media.title LIKE CONCAT('%', search.term, '%') 
              OR media.description LIKE CONCAT('%', search.term, '%') 
              OR media.tags LIKE CONCAT('%', search.term, '%') 
              OR users.username LIKE search.term
         ) AS totalResults,
         MAX(timestamp) AS searchTimestamp
FROM search
WHERE userId = '1'
GROUP BY term
ORDER BY searchTimestamp DESC ;
```

---

**Sidenote**: Using `SELECT *` while having `GROUP BY <columns>` will give you indeterminate results in all other columns, except the `<columns>`. MySQL allows such ill-defined behaviour but it's not good practice.